# Start and stop parameters in init script

Tags: boot, configuration, startup, upstart, init

I have .conf a file in `/etc/init/` with this code at the bottom:

```
start on (started network-interface
          or started network-manager
          or started networking)

stop on (stopping network-interface
         or stopping network-manager
         or stopping networking)
```

I understand this means that it is launched whenever the system boots. Anyway, is it possible to have a more accurate information about each one of these events? `man initctl` does not provide a comprehensive list of them and googling is not very successful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`network-interface`, `network-manager` and `networking` are other Upstart jobs and are defined in `/etc/init/network-interface.conf`, `/etc/init/network-manager.conf` and `/etc/init/networking.conf`.

Have a look at [Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) if you want to learn more about Upstart.

Comment: Quite interesting, thanks @Florian. In my case I cannot find these files in `/etc/init/` neither in all `/etc/`. Anyway, I get the idea that it is whenever the network is available.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? `/etc/init/network-manager.conf` is in package `network-manager`, the other two in `ifupdown` since Ubuntu 10.04. `network-interface` brings an network interface up or down, `network-manager` starts or stops NetworkManager, `networking` brings the network devices in `/etc/network/interfaces` marked as ´auto` up or down.

Comment: I am using an Amazon server, so I cannot know exactly the release of it (supposing it is Ubuntu). Anyway, the main purpose of my question is solved, so thank you very much.